# i cant send email symfony3 neither to confirm registration or for a simple email

Tags: symfony, email, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

Im developping a web application using symfony3 , i'm trying to send confirmation emails using swiftmailer , i want to use confirmation mails and resetting also send direct emails between the users of my app.

Unfortunately i didn't managed to do it yet.
Here is my configs files also the code that i use to send direct mails

Here is my parameter.yml

```
 mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_user: ***********
mailer_password: ********
mailer_encryption: ssl
```

Here is my code config.yml

```
 swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
encryption: ssl
username: '%mailer_user%'
auth_mode: login
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
        from_email:
            address:  *****e@gmail.com
            sender_name: ........
from_email:
        address: ******@gmail.com
        sender_name: ......
```

my code to send email

```
        $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
        $message = $mailer->createMessage()
            ->setSubject("Objet")
            ->setFrom(array('................' => "...."))
            ->setTo('..........)
            ->setBody("Hi");

        $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: This post have a very low quality. Please improve it first.

Comment: Where is the question? A good question, as described in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), have **research effort**, a **clear explanation of the problem** and should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my parameters file:

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: gmail
mailer_user: ************
mailer_password: **********
```

And here is my config file section for swiftmailer:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I use dual verification in Gmail so I generated a application specific password,
[this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) is where you can see how to set one.

This is how I send emails from my controller:

```
private function sendConfirmationEmail($user)
{
    $token = $user->getEmailConfirmationToken();
    $subject = 'Email Confirmation';
    $label = 'Confirm Email';
    $email = $user->getEmail();

    $href = "www.mysymfonyproject.com/app_dev.php/confirm?token=" . $token;

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com')
    ->setTo( $email )
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'Emails/confirm.html.twig',
            array('href' => $href)
        ),
        'text/html'
    );

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return true;
}
```

Also, I see something slightly odd in your config file, it seems you set your "auth_mode" and "encryption" twice both in your parameters.yml and your config.yml. 
Your config.yml file includes your parameters.yml file which is like your parameters.yml get copy-pasted to the config file and in the config file you have mailer settings where some values are pointers to pre set values and other are just values, `%mailer_password%` points to mailer_password parameter value which gets included from the parameters file. It's nothing complicated it's just YML and inclusion. Since you already defined all parameters in the parameters.yml all you need to do in config.yml is to point to them and you can do so by changing your config.yml section for mailer to look like this:

```
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host: "%mailer_host%"
encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
username: "%mailer_user%"
auth_mode: "%mailer_auth_mode%"
password: "%mailer_password%"
spool: { type: memory }
```

Or just copy my application settings and give it a try. A YML developers greeting "Good Luck :)"
PS. YML has to have proper indentation and the suggested edit of your config file is probably not indented correctly so indent it manually.

Comment: Oh, just one more thing. REFRESH YOUR CACHE after major edits. `php bin/console cache:clear`